# Find $f(x,y )$ such that $f_{x},f_{y},f_{yx}$ are continuous,but $f_{xy}$ is not

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, examples-counterexamples

Let $f$ be a function
 of two variables,let$(a,b)$ be a point and let $D$ be an open disk with center $(a,b)$. Assume that $f$ is $\mathcal C^{1}$ on $D$, and $f_{yx}$ exist on $D$. Further, the  mixed second partial derivative $f_{yx}$ is continuous at $(a,b)$,is the other mixed second partial derivative  $f_{xy}$ continuous at $(a,b)?$

I think there must be some counterexample to deny it, I tried to find them.
Do you have some nice counterexamples?

Comment: No. In this case $f_{xy}$ is guaranteed to exist, and $f_{xy} = f_{yx}$ at $(a,b)$.

Comment: @QiyuWen: Haha~ Obversely,$f_{xy}=f_{yx},$ but we can not confirm $f_{xy}$  is continuous at $(a,b)!$

Comment: If the partials are $C^1$ doesn't that mean that they are continuous with continuous derivatives themselves? What am I missing here?

Comment: @AlfredYerger: I am sorry ,I reedit it .

Comment: See my answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/668824/proof-of-frac-partial-frac-partial-fx-y-partial-x-partial-y-frac

Comment: @Ant: I am very sorry to say that your answer have done nothing to deal with this problem.

Comment: Isn't your question wether $f_{xy}$ is continuos knowing that $f_x$, $f_y$, and $f_{yx}$ are continuos?

Comment: @Ant:You only descriptively said "if  $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}$, $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}$ and $\frac{\partial \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}}{\partial y}$ are continuous, then also $\frac{\partial \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}}{\partial x}$ is continuous",but how can we prove it's true rigrously ? I can't take it for granted .

Answer (score 15):

In Dieudonné's  *Elements of Analysis*, volume 1, you'll find an exercise which states that if $f$ is $C^1$ and $f_{xy}$ exists and is continuous on an open set $U$, then $f_{yx}$ exists and equals $f_{xy}$ on $U$. (So, of course, $f_{xy}$ is continuous as well.)

Here's a sketch of the proof. As in the usual proof that a $C^2$ function has equal mixed partial derivatives, we define the second difference function
$$\Delta(h,k) = f(a+h,b+k)-f(a+h,b)-f(a,b+k)+f(a,b).$$
By applying the usual mean value theorem to
$$g(t)=f(t,b+k)-f(t,b),$$
we see that $\Delta(h,k)=\big(f_x(\xi,b+k)-f_x(\xi,b)\big)h$ for some $\xi$ between $a$ and $a+h$. It follows that $\Delta(h,k)=f_{xy}(\xi,\eta)hk$ for some $\eta$ between $b$ and $b+k$. Because $f_{xy}$ is continuous at $(a,b)$, we infer that, for any $\epsilon>0$, there is $\delta>0$ so that whenever $|h|,|k|<\delta$ we have
$$\big|\Delta(h,k)-f_{xy}(a,b)hk\big|<\epsilon|hk|.$$

Now we consider $q(t)=f(a+h,t)-f(a,t)$ and rewrite $\Delta(h,k) = q(b+k)-q(b) = q'(\tau)k$ for some $\tau$ between $b$ and $b+k$. This tells us that
$\Delta(h,k)=\big(f_y(a+h,\tau)-f_y(a,\tau)\big)k$, and so, for $0<|h|,|k|<\delta$ we have
$$\left|\frac{\Delta(h,k)}{hk}-f_{xy}(a,b)\right| = \left|\frac{f_y(a+h,\tau)-f_y(a,\tau)}h-f_{xy}(a,b)\right|<\epsilon.$$
Letting $k\to 0$ (so $\tau\to b$) and using continuity of the first partial derivatives, we obtain
$$\left|\frac{f_y(a+h,b)-f_y(a,b)}h-f_{xy}(a,b)\right|\le\epsilon,$$
from which we conclude that $f_{yx}(a,b)=f_{xy}(a,b)$, as desired.

**Note** that to prove equality of the mixed partials at $(a,b)$ uses only continuity of $f_{xy}$ *at* $(a,b)$. :)

Sadly, however interesting, this leaves open the original question about whether $f_{yx}$ is *continuous* at $(a,b)$ knowing just that $f_{xy}$ is continuous at $(a,b)$.

**EDIT**: It follows from the Baire Category Theorem that if $F$ is differentiable, the set of discontinuities of $F'$ is of first category; in particular, it cannot be a dense open set. This still does not quite answer the question, I guess. It is not *necessary* that $f_{xy}$ be continuous in order for $f_{yx}$ to equal $f_{xy}$ (or to be defined for other reasons), but it sure seems unlikely that there is any counterexample. Anyone else?

Comment: Do you by any chance remember the key idea of the proof?

Comment: It's based on the second difference, just like the usual $C^2$ proof. I'll post a bit more detail tomorrow.

Comment: Is it obvious that there is no counterexample where $f_{xy}$ is continuous at the point $(a,b)$, but not in a neighborhood?

Comment: Ah, good point, @neth. The proof seems to use continuity only at $(a,b)$ to prove existence of $f_{xy}(a,b)$.

Comment: P.S. Perhaps the downvoter was waiting for me to provide the details. If not, would the downvoter be so kind as to let me know what improvement he or she desires?

Comment: @TedShifrin:Thanks for your effort . From your answer we merely know that to prove $f_{xy}(a,b)=f_{yx}(a,b)$,only use continuity of $f_{xy}$ at $(a,b)$.But I have nothing about whether $f_{yx}$ is continuous at $(a,b)$ or not.

Comment: Fair enough. I didn't quite appreciate the subtlety of the question.  I guess, for starters, we need a function with $f_{xy}$ continuous only at $(a,b)$, and I don't know an example even of that.

Comment: ^_^ Thank you all  the same. In fact, your answer is the proof of  H.A.Schwarz Theorem (about the equality of mixed partial derivatives) . That is  widely appeared in many textbooks,If you think  deeply , you will ask whether $f_{xy}$ is continuous at (a,b) or not  naturally.

Comment: No, the usual proof of equality assumes both are continuous. That is in all sorts of textbooks, including my own. ... You might post a separate question asking for an example of a differentiable function with the derivative continuous only at one point. My instincts say there can't be one (Darboux's Theorem).

Comment: Never mind. I've reviewed my own notes from years ago. See the edit.

Comment: I must be missing something.. This answer is correct, meaning that $f_{xy}$ is equal to the continuos $f_{yx}$. So in particular both of them are continuos at $(a,b)$... What am I missing?

Comment: @Ant: We need continuity at $(x,y)$ of one to even prove existence of the other.

Comment: I also would be very interested to know the answer if the continuity condition is dropped. Perhaps someone should post another question on this?

Comment: @NickAlger: I don't understand your question.

Comment: @TedShifrin Just what you are saying at the end of the post. Is there an example where $f_{xy} \neq f_{yx}$ if the derivatives are not required to be continuous?

Comment: @NickAlger: That's a totally standard example that appears in any multivariable analysis or serious multivariable calculus book. Take $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases} xy\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}, & (x,y)\ne (0,0) \\ 0, & (x,y)=(0,0)\end{cases}.$$